# Visual Studio Cannot find file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I run Visual Studio as Administrator, visual Studio cannot find some files. Everything will compile and run though.  When I run normally, it can find all the files without any issues. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Here is what the properties of the exe looks like

Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

[image]

Comment: Look in your project files and see where Visual Studio is expecting those files to be. Maybe it's using some kind of environment variable that doesn't exist (or has a different value) for the admin user.

Comment: Right click file -> properties -> where is VS looking for the file?  Also, need bigger images.

Comment: Will, right click on the Visual Studio exe?

Comment: Will, I updated my question.